# Assign render texture to camera - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I'm learning to make a Audio Visualiser in Unity.
The problem i'm facing is that I have a button, when clicked will programmatically load another scene at runtime, (call it scene Phyllo) Phyllo has a camera. Now there's also a "main" scene, call it UI_v15.
I have put Phyllo's camera view into a render texture.
In [UI_v15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVOVZ.png), I have a `Cube` `GameObject`, i want to assign Phyllo's render texture to the `cube`, so that when the aforementioned button is pressed, the `Cube` can display the camera view from Phyllo. But this is where I failed...

[Phyllo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaHHw.png)

What happened instead is I'm just getting the view from Phyllo like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txa5m.png) (I'm just getting the full view from Phyllo). What instead should happen is the view should be rendering into the Cube I talked about earlier.

When the program runs, the `targetTexture` for `Phyllo`'s camera is not assigned a texture, which it should. As show [here in the red part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uASom.png)

This is the method that gets called when the button (inside UI_v15) is pressed.

```
public void SelectVisualiser()
{

    string sceneName = GetComponent<Button>().GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
    print("scene name " + sceneName);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    VisualiserManager.instance.LoadVisualiser(sceneName);
}
              
public void LoadVisualiser(string name)
{
    //the script PhylloCamera is attached to PhylloCamera in the Phyllo scene.
  
    Camera cam = PhylloCameraRef.instance.phylloCam;
    Material mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
    RenderTexture rt = CreateTexture();
    mat.SetTexture("_MainTex", rt);
    cam.targetTexture = rt;
    display.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[0] = mat;

}
```

the class PhylloCameraRef is attached to the scene Phyllo,which can be loaded at at runtime.

```
    public class PhylloCameraRef : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera phylloCam;
    public static PhylloCameraRef instance;

    
    void Start()
    {
        if (instance is null)
        {
            
            instance = this;
            //getting camera
            phylloCam = gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why Phyllo's camera is not rendering into the Cube? Thanks.

EDIT: Below is the code for CreateTexture()

```
public RenderTexture CreateTexture()
{
    RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(256, 256, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
    rt.Create();
    return rt;
}
```

I forgot to add, for some unknow reason, the camera's targetTexture in UIv_15 is assigned the render texture.
The cube is an actual 3D gameObject.

Comment: Any errors in the console in Unity? Any chance that `CreateTexture` is returning `null` (could you post it) ? Have you [debugged](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) and are you sure that both `SelectVisualizer` and `LoadVisualizer` are being called as expected at all? Simply add some `Debug.Log`s to confirm they at least are getting called when they should

Comment: Also is your "Cube" an actual cube (3D mesh) or is it rather some UI component like e.g. `RawImage`?

Comment: Hi I've made some edits, please check.

Comment: Well if `cam.targetTexture = rt;` assign the texture to the wrong camera .. then you seem to get the wrong camera from `PhylloCameraRef.instance.phylloCam` ... Is it possible you accidentally added the `PhylloCameraRef` to the camera in the `UI_v15` scene which is loaded first so the `instance` referes to the wrong one?

Comment: Why are you doing this on runtime at all? I would simply already create the `RenderTexture` in the editor and assign it right away to the material and the according camera(s) .. then you don't have to do it on runtime at all but rather simply load and unload according scenes ...